# UFW - can I add a domain?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

This will work from the docs:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.0.2 to any port 22
```

But..will this work?

```
 sudo ufw allow proto tcp from foo.bar.com to any port 22
```

I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently not

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.254.13 to any port 22
Rule added
```

then

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from foo.bar.com to any port 22
ERROR: Bad source address
```

UFW is just a front end no netfilter/iptables which will take a name and convert it to an address however this is not good practice as the name is only resolved when the rule is added and changes are not notified to netfilter.

Comment: What's the proper solution to this problem that doesn't involve resorting to a layer 7 switch or something external to the local machine?  I've been looking at Squid, but for HTTPS traffic there doesn't seem to be a way to force clients to use Squid.  (I'm thinking of Google Chrome in this case.)  And `/etc/hosts` is also ignored for HTTPS traffic.